# How do we use the $∃$ elimination technique —and ping-pong — to show $\vdash (∃x)A → (∃x)(B → A).$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

How do we use the ∃ elimination technique —and ping-pong — to show $\vdash (∃x)A → (∃x)(B → A)$. ??

Can I just use the deduction theorem to moveover the $(∃x)A \vdash (∃x)(B → A)$

and start $(∃x)(A)$ as an Hyp?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ping-pong'?

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma), @Nika.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't know what that link to ping-pong has to do with first order logic.  But $B\to A$ is a logical consequence of $A$, so it's just a matter of wrapping $\exists I$ and $\exists E$ around that.

Comment: Completly non-sense... The link you have provided has nothing to do with logic. Some author speaks of [Ping-pong argument](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAwgCTgnycC&pg=PA102) in the context of proving a *bi-conditional*. But your problem has no bi-conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Assume exists x with A(x).
Whence assert A(c) for some unused constant c.
Thus B implies A(c).
As c is not used in B, exists x with (B implies A(x)).